# Div ontop of every other div

Tags: html, css

I have a simple question, and want to know if you can solve it for me..

Anyway, the question is, how do i place a box in the right side of the page, that wont affect any of the appearence of the css that is currently on the page :)

Comment: Position it with `absolute` or `fixed`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: absolute;`. To define the position, you can use the `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` properties to specify the respective offsets. In your case, you probably want `right`:

```
.rightbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; /*how many pixels from top*/
    right: 25px; /*how many pixels from right*/
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

If you want your `div` to stay visible even after you scroll, use `position: fixed;`.

Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/KdhLy/).

Comment: Didnt work.. It made a lot of space to the right and therefor made a scroll bar :/

Comment: @Matthew Change the `width` of your `#admin` to `200px`, or `.admincontainer` to `100px`.

Comment: @Matthew Because currently, `.admincontainer` is wider than `#admin`.

Comment: it worked :)
New question: Question: How can i make the box the right on laebelliving.dk follow the screen as the visitor scrolls?

Comment: @Matthew Use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`